# Are Use case specification the same as Use case description?

Tags: uml, use-case

I know what use case descriptions are. But when people say use case specification is it the same as use case descriptions?

Answer (score 1):

For my understanding, the specification includes both the diagram(s) plus the textual descriptions, but you should make sure your stakeholders' understanding is the same as your own if they use such wording.